# How to inherit functionalities to reduce repeating codes in enums?

Tags: java, enums

In a Java application I'm working on, I have a number of enums which ended up having a static `fromString` method in them for converting a string to its actual enum value.

So, I thought I could have a "base" class from which all my enums can extend without have to repeat that code all the time. Since enums cannot extend classes, I've planned to do is that I might be able to do that through an interface instead.

What I've is the following:

```
public interface IBaseEnum {

    String enumVal = null;

    public static <T extends Enum<T> & IBaseEnum> Enum<T> fromString(String strVal) {
        if (strVal == null) return null;
        // T.values() has error because T is not recognised to have the method values()
        for (T myEnum : T.values()) {
            if (myEnum.enumVal.equals(strVal.toUpperCase())) {
                return myEnum;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then, to inherit that static method, I will implement `IBaseEnum` in my actual Enum:

```
public enum Colour implements IBaseEnum {
   Red("red");
   //...
}
```

However, I'm having issues with the types in `IBaseEnum`. The line `T.values()` is having error because the generic type `T` cannot be referenced back to the enum itself and so it is complaining that the method `values()` is not found.

Is this the right way to inherit functionalities in enum? Otherwise, how can I inherit methods in enums so that I don't have to copy/paste and repeat a same set of methods in every single enums?

Comment: My initial thought is that the thing you want to achieve is going to result in "misusing" an Enum. If you want to use inheritance, use classes. If you want to abstract your types to a "valuelist", use an enum. By the way, isn't .valueOf() the method you are searching for? (Also see: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/enum/enum-tutorial/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few reasons why your code would not work, of which I should mention:

- `String enumVal = null;`: `IBaseEnum` being an interface, `numVal` gets the implicit `public`, `static`, and `final` modifiers. However, you intend `enumVal` to be an instance property.
- `T.values()`: of course this doesn't compile. But even if it could (or you had the class instance), you still wouldn't be able to make this dynamic. Static methods are picked at compile time. The only way (that I know) to make it work dynamically would be to use reflection, of course passing in the class object of the enum.

Because you want to be able to call `Color.fromString(...)`, you have no choice but to declare this as a static method in each enum class. With that said, I think the most you can reuse from your logic is the lookup code (again, that's unless you use reflection).

To reuse the lookup logic, you can change the contract of `IBaseEnum` to make it declare a method that that returns the `enumVal` value. Beside that, the `values()` method can be invoked by the enum classes themselves. Here's what it can look like:

```
interface IBaseEnum {

    String enumVal();

    public static <T extends Enum<T> & IBaseEnum> T 
                 fromString(String strVal, T[] values) {

        if (strVal == null)
            return null;

        for (T myEnum : values) {
            if (myEnum.enumVal().equalsIgnoreCase(strVal)) {
                return myEnum;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And that will lead to an enum class like the following:

```
enum Colour implements IBaseEnum {
    VAL1("string")
    ;

    private final String val;

    Colour(String v) {
        this.val = v;
    }

    @Override
    public String enumVal() {
        return this.val;
    }

    public static Colour fromString(String s) {
        return IBaseEnum.fromString(s, values());
    }
}
```

Remember: if `enumVal()` is intended to return just the enum literal, then you can get rid of all this complexity by just using the `valueOf` method available in all enums. Only do this if the comparison of your values needs custom logic.